# Rendering a partial form on a static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a static page I named home and used scaffold to generate a form called Specialists and when I try to render the form using the following  code

```
<%= render :partial => 'specialists/form', locals: {specialist: @specialist} %>
```

I get the following error `undefined method "errors" for nil:NilClass` and here is the code snippet of the error

Extracted source (around line #2):

```
<%= form_with(model: specialist, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if specialist.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(specialist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this specialist from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
```

I tried to check previous similar questions but none of them had this error because of this, I am pretty new to Ruby on Rails.

Controller code

```
class SpecialistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_specialist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /specialists
  # GET /specialists.json
  def index
    @specialists = Specialist.all
  end

  # GET /specialists/1
  # GET /specialists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /specialists/new
  def new
    @specialist = Specialist.new
  end

  # GET /specialists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /specialists
  # POST /specialists.json
  def create
    @specialist = Specialist.new(specialist_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @specialist.save
        format.html { redirect_to @specialist, notice: 'Specialist was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @specialist }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @specialist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /specialists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /specialists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @specialist.update(specialist_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @specialist, notice: 'Specialist was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @specialist }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @specialist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /specialists/1
  # DELETE /specialists/1.json
  def destroy
    @specialist.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to specialists_url, notice: 'Specialist was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_specialist
      @specialist = Specialist.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def specialist_params
      params.require(:specialist).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :phone, :email, :interest)
    end
end'
```

Comment: Make sure `@specialist` is defined in your controller action

Comment: Please post your controller code

Comment: I have added the code of the controller to the question @Dyaniyal Nadar

Comment: In what page/action are you using the render code? in `index` or `new`?

Comment: I'm using it in the static page "home" @Aguardientico

Comment: @mr-nash so, you are trying to use a variable that you didn't set `@specialist`, is ok to use an "static" page but you need to route that page to an action in a controller and in the action set `@specialist` to be able to use in your static page "home"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

On the controller, I think missing something, try the following

```
def new
    @specialist = Specialist.new
end
```

On the form

```
<%= form_with model: @specialist, local: true do |form| %>
```

Or update form like below

```
<%= form_with scope: :specialist, url: specialists_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

Rails 5 guides say about validation see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-some-validation)

About `form_with` you can learn more the following [link](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a)

Hope it helps

Comment: I've just posted the controller on the question and `@specialist = Specialist.new` is defined already

Comment: @MrNash try to removing this part `, locals: {specialist: @specialist}` and updating `form_with model: @specialist, local: true do |form|`

Comment: And `if specialist.errors.any?` to `if @specialist.errors.any?` @MrNash

Comment: I get the same error after making this change 

`<%= form_with model: @specialist, local: true do |form| %>
  <% if @specialist.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(specialist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this specialist from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>`

Comment: Restart the server and then try

Comment: Same result @fool-dev

Comment: The `<% if @specialist.errors.any? %>` total part of error block use upper the form, I mean use this outside of the form

Comment: @MrNash Updated the answer based what saying the rails guide

Comment: Removing the whole if blocke that contains `specialist.errors` is what seems to work but I don't know if I should define it anywhere else @fool-dev

Comment: I have used partials on my projects like on the new page `<%= render "partials/form" %>` and `<%= render "commons/error",  obj: @variable %>`  I mean two partials one  for form & one error then the `if obj.errors.any?`